# Remove animation glitch

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have an animation with a glitch inside it, a wrong position, which I'd like to remove, but cannot find a way to do it simply and thru. This is supposed to be easy, so probably I'm missing something:

[image]

I've marked the wrong pose at frame 26, corresponding to the body to the right which sit still, while he should be backflipping.
How do I remove this pose? The immediately previous and following ones are correct.
Thank you.

EDIT: the blend. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A8jLuwVmanUdaWsiUq2yyVkTclzNR3l8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no keyframe at frame 26. Because you seem to have imported a 30 fps animation into a 24 fps project, a lot of keys are not on full frames.

The strange movement is the result of interpolation of the root bone, the hip.

The curves of the hip bone show the sudden change.

[image: movement]

You can take any of the adjacent keys and move them onto the interpolated frame.

[image: move keyframe]

Comment: Yes. I've reimported at 30 fps and everything is fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are no keyframes at the frame 26. If that's right, then the issue is not a wrong pose, but actually either a lack of pose to better define what happens between the previous and next keyframes, or it's actually the other keyframes in fault, like a gimbal lock or something.

It's complicated to tell more just from this screenshot you shared, so maybe show us your animation via a [Viewport Render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html) (or [OpenGL Render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/opengl.html) in Blender v2.79 and prior), and/or give us the .blend file so we can dig in.

Comment: I added the blend. Thx